# reading value from custom element while submitting in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have custom component which I am importing in my another Component as a Element tag. My custom Component consist of dropdown values. I want to read value the value of in my element tag when I submit my form

custom component :

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import countryList from 'react-select-country-list'

function CountrySelector() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const options = useMemo(() => countryList().getData(), [])

  const changeHandler = value => {
    setValue(value)
  }

  return <Select options={options} value={value} onChange={changeHandler} />
}

export default CountrySelector
```

i want to use that custom component country selector values on my submit button:

main component:

```
import react from 'react';
import CountrySelector from '../../helpers/CountrySelector';
import IdType from '../../helpers/IdType';
import ProofOfAddress from '../../helpers/ProofOfAddress';

const submitForm=(e)=>{
    //debugger;
e.preventDefault();
console.warn(e.target)
};


const IdentityVerification = (props) => {
    const saveUser=(e)=>{
        console.warn({e});
    }
    return (
      <form onSubmit={submitForm} > 
        <div className='app'>
        <label >Choose Issuing Country/region</label>
          <CountrySelector/>
          <label >Select ID Type</label>
          <IdType/>
          <label >Proof of Address</label>
          <ProofOfAddress/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-actions">
          <button >Submit</button>
          
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  };
  
  export default IdentityVerification;
```

how can i read values?

Comment: You should store values in the parent component and pass them into CountrySelector component by props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to handle this would be to move the state and your `changeHandler` function into the parent component and pass the handler down to the child as a prop.

```
const IdentityVerification = (props) => {
   const [value, setValue] = useState('')
   const changeHandler = value => {
     setValue(value)
   }
   return (
        // ...

        <CountrySelector onChange={changeHandler}/>

       // ...
);
```

and in your child:

```
function CountrySelector({changeHandler}) {
  // .... 
  return <Select options={options} value={value} onChange={changeHandler} />
}
```

Comment: thankyou Will, also can i have to send props to child as well as i am getting countries names from libraryvalue={value} and options={options}    const options = useMemo(() => countryList().getData(), [])